# android edittext get first two input value's sum

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have one edittext and for example I put in12345. I want to check if the first two numbers' sum is >0 then do something. I don't know how to check first two elements' sum.

```
if(pirinfouserid.getText().toString().indexOf(2)>0)
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

If anyone knows a solution please help me

Thanks

Comment: Do you have problem in getting the text of the editText or converting it into a number?

Comment: i don't know how to sum first two element @thepace.my code is wrong.i don't know solution

Comment: Please clear your question. what you actually want to do.

Comment: i.e of "12345" you want to sum "1" + "2" ?

Comment: Check Brovoker's answer.It will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get first two char from String input from user:

```
String firstTwoDigit = s.substring(0, 
                  Math.min(pirinfouserid.getText().toString().length(), 1));
```

Now get  sum of two digits using [Find Sum of Digits in Java Algorithm](http://java67.blogspot.in/2014/06/write-program-to-find-sum-of-digits-in-java.html) :

```
// Parse String to Integer 
int sum = 0;
int digits = Integer.parseInt(firstTwoDigit);
while (digits != 0) {
 int lastdigit = digits % 10;
 sum += lastdigit;
 digits /= 10;
}
if(sum>0){
  // do your work
}else{
  // do your work
}
```

Using this way you will separate digit sum logic from other code which you can later parameterized for finding sum of more digits.

Before using `String.substring` and `Integer.parseInt` also add `null` and `length` check for String

Answer (score 1):

```
int num1=Integer.parseInt(pirinfouserid.getText().toString().charAt(0));
int num2=Integer.parseInt(pirinfouserid.getText().toString().charAt(1));
int sum=num1+num2;
if(sum>0)
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: IndexOf method returns the index of the found element, not the element at the given index, I think you would want to use charAt

Comment: sorry for the mistake. i have made the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = pirinifouserid.getText().toString();

int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,1));
int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(1,2));
int sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;

if (sum > 0) ...
```

Comment: You want to add an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` handling around the lines with `substring` methods.

Comment: @Brovoker thank you,but for example i inputed 1234567898765 and etc and how i can sum last 7 element's sum ?

Comment: If the input is "1" (one digit).

Answer (score 0):

Please find relevant comments inline

```
String input = pirinifouserid.getText().toString();
if(input.length()>2){
    try{
        int num1= Integer.parseInt(input.indexOf(0)); // Handle NumberFormatException
        int num2= Integer.parseInt(input.indexOf(1));// Handle NumberFormatException
        int sum = num1 + nm2;
        if (sum > 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wrong",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){ 
        // DO what you think is correct. Probably show an error message 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have syntacs error in this line int num2= Integer.parseInt(input.indexOf(1)); @hepace